# Identify each $x_n$ with a function $L_n \in (\mathcal{l}^1)^*$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $x_n=(0,...,0,1,..1,..)$ be a sequence whose first n components are all equal 0 and the rest of the terms are equal 1. Identify each $x_n$ with a function $L_n \in (\mathcal{l}^1)^*$, and then show that for every **x** $\in \mathcal{l}^1$, $L_n($**x**$) \rightarrow 0$. Can we say that $L_n$ converges weakly to zero in $(\mathcal{l}^1)^*$?

We say that {$x_n$} converges weakly in X (and we write $x_n \rightarrow^w x$ if every $L \in X^*$, $\lim_{x \to \infty}{L(x_n)}=L(x)$

What I need help one in is determine the function? Can someone help me with that portion?$\:\:$

Answer (score 0):

$L_n$ converges weak-star to zero in $(l^1)^*$, since
$$
L_n(x) = \sum_{i=n}^\infty x_i 
$$
converges to zero for $n\to \infty$ and $x\in l^1$.

The identification $x_n \to L_n$ via
$$
L_n(x) := \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_{n,i}x_i
$$
is a standard tool in the study of dual spaces of the sequence spaces $l^p$.

Comment: So the function of $x_n$ is what?

Comment: The functional $L_n\in (l^1)^*$ is given the infinite sum I wrote.